Suspend clicks events on fragment bellow
I have in a frag_container a fragment named Fragment1. I display another Fragment2 with
 FragmentTransaction transaction = ((ActivityMain) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.setCustomAnimations(0, 0, R.anim.open_main, R.anim.close_next);
            transaction.add(R.id.frag_container, fragment);
            transaction.commit();

I use add and not replace from some animation reasons.Fragment1 is under Fragment2, is hidden. My problem is that any click on Fragment2 is intercepted by Fragment1 too.
How can I block that Fragment1 to ignore any clicks as long Fragment2 is attached to the same fragment container? I need to suspend Fragment1 to intercept click so long Fragment2 is displayed and recover clicking events from moment when Fragment2 was removed.

Add android:clicable="true" to Fragment2 root layout xml file

why to do that? Fragment2 already get click events.

To prevent fragment2 sends click event to others below it

i need clicks on fragment 2
